# Dynamics 365 Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient(connectionString) takes 15 seconds to open

Tags: api, dynamics-crm

We are developing and C# MCV API that calls Dynamics using the SDK. But we are having some performance issues.

Why is it that makes it take this long to just open the connection?

After the first call is cached, the rest of the calls are fast, but 15 seconds every time seems like really bad performance.

These lines of code takes 15 seconds to go over.

`connectionString = AuthType=Office365;Username=User;Password=Password;`

`CrmServiceClient conn = new Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient(connectionString)`

Comment: I'm going heavily back and forth from Europe to NA region in my recent developments and code never takes more than 2-3 seconds to run, the issue might be on your end. Is it this slow from the browser too ? I'd consider a support ticket. Afterthought: I'm seeing warnings about service degradation in several of our customer's O365 portals so it might also be an issue on *their* end.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth that sort of performance is pretty normal from my experience.

If it's a major issue you could try some of the [other authentication methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn688177.aspx), [server to server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790168.aspx) authentication, or even other web services such as the [Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt593051.aspx). *I've no idea if any of these will improve performance, it's just something you could try*.

I suppose alternatively you stick with `CrmServiceClient(connectionString)` but look at implementing some sort of Always On type functionaility to avoid the service construction time.